# How do I reenable mkdir and other commands from the nav bar win7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

I want to be able to use command line commands from the explorer bar, like it used to be able to, preferably without 3rd party software.

This was in another thread as a comment, but I don't have the rep to post there...Pretty sure it hasn't been posted as a question yet.. I KNOW you USED to be able to do dos commands through the nav bar in explorer but one of the windows updates in the last few months nuked it (at least on my box, win7 pro, legit license)...I need it back...any ideas?  Maybe group policies?  I MAY have a virus, I just switched to MSSE and I don't really trust it, but I was fine before that and haven't noticed anything viruslike otherwise...

It didn't turn out to be a virus, just my lazy maintenance of the OS.

Once again, I want to be able to use command line commands from the explorer bar, like it used to be able to, preferably without 3rd party software.

Also I'm using Win7-Ultimate now.

Comment: Which is the output when u have tried to run mkdir command?

Comment: It searches for mkdir [folder name] on Bing.

Comment: Also, once again, why did this question get downvoted?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**Explorer Toolbar Editor**](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.16) to reset the toolbar or even add new buttons:

> **Explorer Toolbar Editor** is powerful and easy-to-use software that helps you add or remove buttons from the Windows Explorer toolbar in
>   Windows 7. Unlike other existing programs, Explorer Toolbar Editor
>   supports multiple folder types and displays the current set of buttons
>   for each one. Also, you can use it to reorder the toolbar buttons.
>
> **Features**
>
> - view current button sets for each folder type
> - add/remove buttons to individual or all folder types
> - change the order of buttons on the toolbar
> - restore the default set of buttons

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Not exactly the answer to my question, and while it WOULD be a band-aid for this problem, I'd have to add buttons for every command I want.  I thought I was clear in my question, I want the command line to work from the explorer bar like it used to.  Preferably without 3rd party software.